# Microsoft Azure OAUTH2.0 - How can Multiple Source Clients call Azure OAUTH2.0 authentication

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory

I create an Azure APIM instance, register it as an app in AD and then create a OAUTH2.0 server under APIM which is setup using the clientid/secret key of above registered app. I make a dummy API under this APIM and then protect it with this OAUTH2.0 server. I also add a JWT policy on my api to look for a token and authenticate against the tenant-id.(No claims mentioned).

Now lets say, i have a Customer (ABC) and for that i register another app in AD and create its Clientid/secret. Customer generates its token with the help of token endpoint (this endpoint is given under Endpoints tab of AD app registration option). Customer calls the API with this token and it works.

Issue: I didn't give any permission for my APIM App in AD to the Client App in AD  but it still works, which essentially means that any Clientid/secret from any app registered in AD will go through my JWT policy of the API. Because it is just validating against the tenantid. How can we stop this and make sure that it works only for a customer to which permissions is given.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the major things I mentioned in my recent article: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1.

Any app of type Web App/API in Azure AD can get a valid access token for any API in that Azure AD tenant.
Even before any permissions are given to it.
This is kind of a "feature" I guess.

Quote from the article:

> If you only require an authenticated user, any confidential client in your Azure AD can acquire an access token for your API and call it. So it is important that you implement the user_impersonation scope check at minimum.

Now since your caller will call your API as itself, you need to implement an App Permission.
You can see how those are defined here: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad.

Then implement a check that ensures the `roles` claim contains the `value` of the app permission you defined.
The claim will be a string array, so some kind of contains check needs to be made.
This will then require that this app permission is granted the caller before they can make the call successfully.

If you also want to allow delegated calls (i.e. calls on behalf of a user),
then add an optional requirement for the `user_impersonation` scope.
Those are stored in a single string claim (`scp`), space-separated.
So for that one you'll need a contains check on the string.